# col-md is not working in IE 8-Respond.js is not working in IE 8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having Internet Explorer version 8.0.6001.18702.When i viewed  http://getbootstrap.com/css/ link .col-md-1 class are viewed as block level elements.

Respond.js is not working in Internet Explorer.
But in other latest browser working fine.
I tried the same problem in my localhost i coudn't get the solution
Kindly explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IE8 is outdated. The final version of IE8 was 8.0.7601.17514. Use Windows Update.

See also https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/310